# A lot of flushleft's causes longtable to overfull page

Tags: tables, xetex, vertical-alignment, longtable

I'm  using `longtable` to write tables that span across pages. But when I use it after some environments like `flushright`, it overfull page and overlap page number like this.
[image]

Here is code (I'm using XeLaTex):

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{extreport}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm}
\geometry{right=1cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}        
    \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{flushright}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{140mm}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        Test & Test \\ \hline
        Test & Test \\ \hline
        Test & Test \\ \hline
        Test & Test \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And when I add one more `Test & Test \\ \hline`, table magically typesets normally. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's the purpose of the `flushleft` and `flushright` environments?

Comment: My page consists of blocks, some blocks are flushed left, some right, some even in center. And this blocks must be vertically separated by some space. This is title page for my thesis and it must be formatted according my university rules. Should I apply raggedleft/right/centering on my paragraphs and insert vspaces instead?

Comment: a title page????  I'm surprised that you ever want automatic page breaking in a title page, why longtable?

Comment: It is something like this http://imgur.com/a/edUak, tables everywhere, and may contains some long content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is so much shrinkable glue on the page it makes `longtable`'s job of finding a safe place to switch the output routine rather difficult.

In an ideal world it would always get this right automatically, but in this world, adding a `\clearpage` immediately before `\begin{longtable}` gives the package a helping hand.